# How to convert frozenset to normal sets or list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have a frozen set

```
[frozenset({'a', 'c,'}), frozenset({'h,', 'a,'})]
```

I want to convert it to a normal list like

```
[['a', 'c,'],['a,', 'd,']...]
```

What method should I use?

Comment: 1. You have a list of frozensets, you want a list of lists. 2. Have you tried using `list`? 3. Why doesn't the output match the input?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
sets=[frozenset({'a', 'c,'}), frozenset({'h,', 'a,'})]

print([list(x) for x in sets])
```

The list comprehension will convert every frozenset in your list of sets and put them into a new list. That's probably what you want.

You can also you map, `map(list, sets)`. Please be aware, that in Python 3, if you want the result of `map` as list you need to manually convert it using `list`, otherwise, it's just a `map object` which looks like `<map object 0xblahblah>`

Answer (score 5):

We can convert frozenset object `x` to list or set by using list() or set() on it. So we can do this on each item in the list containing frozensets as mentioned in the another by [Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2153965/ivan)

```
>>> x=frozenset(['a','b','c','d'])
>>> print(x)
frozenset({'c', 'd', 'a', 'b'})
>>> y=list(x)
>>> y
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
>>> y = set(x)
>>> y
{'c', 'd', 'a', 'b'}
```